# Consequences of the Dedekind conjecture on the ratio of Zeta functions

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

A conjecture of Dedekind asserts that for any finite algebraic extension
*F* of **Q**, the zeta function $\zeta_F(s)$ is divisible by the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$. That
is, the quotient $\zeta_K(s)/\zeta(s)$ is entire. More generally, Dedekind conjectured that if
*K* is a finite extension of *F*, then $\zeta_K(s)/\zeta_F(s)$ should be entire.

Normally in texts this conjecture is mentioned as a consequence of more general conjectures, like Artin's or Selberg's. But what about the consequences of the Dedekind conjecture itself. For example, we know that the Riemann zeta function gives us much information about the distribution of primes, so I was wondering what (if any) facts about **Q** or fields in general are known to follow if the Dedekind conjecture is true.

Comment: Given that the Artin conjecture itself doesn't have any particularly dramatic consequences, one should hardly expect an answer here. Most interesting applications (beyond Cebotarev which can be proved without Artin) require not only that these functions are holomorphic but that they don't have zeros in Re(s)>1/2 either, which is a harder problem.

Comment: Thank you. And I guess the zeroes question is not part of Artin conjecture. There is a name for the zeroes conjecture? And what would be an interesting application?

Comment: “Is there a name for the zeroes conjecture” : GRH

Comment: @Mr.Basil Thank you.

Comment: It is a particular case of Artin conjecture (telling about the asymptotic of $\sum_{p\le x} tr(\rho(p)) $ where $\rho$ is a finite image complex Galois representation) the consequences are the same for particular representations.